# Bundle.js from create-react-app loads slowly with Docker Toolbox

Tags: reactjs, containers, create-react-app, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I have a react web app built using create-react-app that is currently running inside a container. The development `bundle.js` is kinda big ~2mb. But, it takes the webpack-dev-sever that is running inside the container more than 30 seconds to load the bundle. Is there any way to speed this up? I'm using Docker Toolbox with Windows 7

**Screen Shot:**

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` is inherently slow when used to enable hot reload for webpack in a docker container. A better alternative is to run the webpack stuff outside the container

Comment: Is there a way to do this (outside of the container) with create-react-app? Webpack is not accessible in create-react-app.